# ansible nested jinja expression

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to generate a file using a template with Ansible and Jinja2 but I can't seem to get a variable to be recognized.

I have numerous datacenters (dc) and this is declared as "dc" in my hosts_vars file for the host I am running this playbook against. I can call "dc" within the template and it works. My problem lies when I need to call a group of that "dc",

i.e. my datacenter is 'tucson' and I have a group within 'tucson' that is called 'tucson-linux'. I need to be able to dynamically get the list of hosts from 'tucson-linux'. I can do this statically with the following code, In this case, I am grabbing 'gui_addr' from each host in that group.

My template:

```
{
 "cluster": {
  "name": "{{ dc|upper }}-Cluster",
  "config": {
   "ip-address": [ {% for host in groups['tucson-linux'] %}"{{ hostvars[host].gui_addr + '",' }}{% endfor %} ]
 }
}
```

I've tried different variations of substituting 'tucson' with the "dc" var but no luck, I have read that you can't nest jinja expressions which appears to be what I am trying to do

```
{
 "cluster": {
  "name": "{{ dc|upper }}-Cluster",
  "config": {
   "ip-address": [ {% for host in groups['{{dc}}-linux'] %}"{{ hostvars[host].gui_addr + '",' }}{% endfor %} ]
 }
}
```

The error,

```
 fatal: [tucson-server-01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{dc}}-linux'"}
```

Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've gotten into Jinja template land, you don't need to use more curly braces; you can use the [Jinja template language](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) (which bears a strong resemblance to Python in many cases).

In particular, where you write:

```
{% for host in groups['{{dc}}-linux'] %}
```

If you were in, say, Python, you'd concatenate the variable `dc` and the string `-linux`.  Jinja has [a specific string concatenation operator](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#other-operators) and I think this should work

```
{% for host in groups[dc ~ '-linux'] %}
```